# onnx predict model (robertasequenceclassification) gives AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

I'm using this collab as a base https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11OZknA7er__NgH-Yje7__LY5v-huYE0P?usp=share_link

The base collab uses a single query (sentence) and passes it through the detector. My use case requires me to pass several inputs (74 rows) into the detector. I'm using a dataframe that's a xlsx file converted into a dataframe.

The error appears on this part of the code

```
logits_onnx = ort_session.run(None, input_list)
```

The relevant code is as follows

```
def encode_df(dataframe):
    profiles = dataframe.apply(lambda row: tokenizer.encode(list(row), axis=1, add_special_tokens=True))
    return profiles

def gpt_detector(query, onnx_path= ONNX_path):
    input_list = []
    start = time.time()
    model_name = 'roberta-large'
    tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_path)
    encode_query = encode_df(query)
    tokens_onnx = encode_query.values.tolist()
    all_tokens = len(tokens_onnx)
    tokens_onnx = tokens_onnx[:tokenizer.model_max_length - 2]
    used_tokens = len(tokens_onnx)
    for x in tokens_onnx:
      input_list.append(torch.tensor([tokenizer.bos_token_id] + x + [tokenizer.eos_token_id]).unsqueeze(0))
    input_tensor = torch.stack(input_list)
    mask = torch.ones_like(input_tensor)

    #no gradient calculation
    with torch.no_grad():
        ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: to_numpy(input_tensor)}
        logits_onnx = ort_session.run(None, input_tensor)
        probs_onnx = softmax(logits_onnx[0])
        end = time.time()
    total_time = np.round(end - start, decimals=2)
    fake_onnx, real_onnx = probs_onnx[0][0], probs_onnx[0][1]
    fake_onnx = np.round(fake_onnx*100, decimals=2)
    real_onnx = np.round(real_onnx*100, decimals=2)

    return "fake onnx ", fake_onnx, "real onnx ", real_onnx, "used tokens ", used_tokens, "total time ", total_time
```

This function is simply called as `gpt2_detector(df)`

The full error is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-74c8127e0b65> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 df = pd.DataFrame(df)
      3 #profiles_input = df.values.tolist()
----> 4 gpt_detector(df)

1 frames
<ipython-input-13-2bd38da3931e> in gpt_detector(query, onnx_path)
     39         #parameters = output_names, input_feed, run_options
     40         #returns = list of results
---> 41         logits_onnx = ort_session.run(None, input_list)
     42         # logits = model(tokens.to(device), attention_mask=mask.to(device))[0]
     43         #apply softmax

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py in run(self, output_names, input_feed, run_options)
    214             sess.run([output_name], {input_name: x})
    215         """
--> 216         self._validate_input(list(input_feed.keys()))
    217         if not output_names:
    218             output_names = [output.name for output in self._outputs_meta]

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I don't understand why the model is complaining about Tensor object not having attribute keys.

Is it /really/ complaining that the object is not compatible? Or what is wrong with this?

**UPDATED CODE with fixes + trying to convert list into tensor

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in the ```for x in x in tokens_onnx:``` loop, are you supposed to be overwriting the ```input_list``` for each item in tokens_onnx?  Since you're trying to access ```keys``` off input_list,  aren't you supposed to make that into a dictionary of some sort?   (Just curious... I don't understand that code that much..)

Comment: @ewokx ah that is a mistake. I can't shake c++ syntax off my brain. Thanks for catching that!